# Executing Groovy script from JSON

Tags: json, http, curl, groovy

If I want to send multiline string in JSON using **curl** the only way is to concatenate string using spaces. So this is working. But what to do if I send groovy script which will be run? Like in **content** property:

```
{
  "name": "helloWorld",
  "content": "repository.createDockerHosted('docker_private', 8082_1, null) repository.createDockerHosted('docker_private_2', 8082, null)",
  "type": "groovy"
}
```

Is it possible to inform groovy compiler that there are two instructions? Maybe by adding some special character to **content** value?

**Thanks for help :)**

Comment: If you question there is just, how to separate two groovy instructions, the answer is `;`. It might help, if you could put that as the subject.

Comment: Yeah, that was it :) Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

To execute a string as Groovy script, the standard pattern is to use `GroovyShell` with a `Binding`:

```
class Repository {
    def createDockerHosted(a, b, c) {
        println "TRACER createDockerHosted $a $b $c"
    }
}

def content = "repository.createDockerHosted('docker_private', 8082_1, null) ; repository.createDockerHosted('docker_private_2', 8082, null)"

def binding = new Binding()
binding.setProperty('repository', new Repository())
def shell = new GroovyShell(binding)
shell.evaluate(content)
```

(Note in the above that `content` has `;` to separate the two statements) Output:

```
$ groovy Example.groovy 

TRACER createDockerHosted docker_private 80821 null
TRACER createDockerHosted docker_private_2 8082 null
```

So for your situation (if I understand it), the only issue is how to extract `content` from JSON:

```
def jsonStr = '''
{
  "name": "helloWorld",
  "content": "repository.createDockerHosted('docker_private', 8082_1, null) ; repository.createDockerHosted('docker_private_2', 8082, null)",
  "type": "groovy"
}
'''

def jsonMap = new groovy.json.JsonSlurper().parseText(jsonStr)
def content = jsonMap['content']
```